# Django Authentication Token, can't open the admin page

Tags: django, authentication

I'm trying to validate my users with Token Authentication, the problem is that I don't know how to add a header with the token, so I can enter into my admin panel. Before I implemented this method if I typed http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin I could acces it with no problems.

Here's my models.py

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    open = models.FloatField()
    close = models.FloatField()
    volume = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticker


# This code is triggered whenever a new user has been created and saved to the database
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Here's my views.py (I think this is were I have to change some things):

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def stock_list(request, format=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        stocks = Stock.objects.all()
        serializer = StockSerializer(stocks, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = StockSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
def stock_detail(request, pk, format=None):
    try:
        stock = Stock.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Stock.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = StockSerializer(stock)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = StockSerializer(stock, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        stock.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Here's my urls app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^stocks/$', views.stock_list),
    url(r'^stocks/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.stock_detail),

]
```

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)

And here's my url project:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('companies.urls')),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token),
]
```

I know that the token is created when an user is registered, if I type :

```
curl --data "username=admin&password=password" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/
```

I obtain the token of the admin, any idea how can I add the header with the token?

Comment: that's depend on your request. the method/syntax will be change by language like.. postman, python, js but basically you just need to pass token in headers

Answer (score 0):

The exact method to add header will change by how you are making request
but bewlo line should contain in headers to authenticate user

```
Authorization:Token <token>
```

make sure you have included `'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'` in your `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` of rest framework

EX.

Sample curl request:

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/example/ -H 'Authorization: Token <token>'
```

In python script you can execute below commands:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'authorization': "Token <token>",
    }

response = requests.request("<request-typle>", <url>, data=<payload-if-any>, headers=headers)  # while making nay request you need to mention headers as dictionary and `authorization` key to specify token
```

If you are writing tests then you can write it as:

```
self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + <token>)
```

read detail in [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) thread

Comment: Any idea how could I use the admin panel again? When I try to enter like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin it dosn't work anymore

Comment: you don't have urlpatterns for it

Comment: Has anyone found out how to use the admin panel while still implementing Token authentication?

Comment: @Xceptions Token authentication doesn't impact in any ways with admin panel, as it's been already stated earlier, you follow the procedure of admin panel, i.e. add urlpatterns for it and it will work!

Comment: yeah thanks, I've got it figured out. The api should be created as a separate app from the main app where the admin panel runs from.

Comment: @Xceptions, no it is not required, you can keep theme together in one app. but Token authentication doesn't impact admin panel because Django can support multiple Auth class Simultaneously.